# Is asyncio.run_in_executor multithreading?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

The event loop is meant to be thread-specific, since asyncio is about cooperative multitasking using single thread. So I don't understand how `asyncio.run_in_exceutor` work together with `ThreadPoolExcecutor`?

Comment: That's precisely the point, `run_in_executor` lets you run code outside of the event loop (using the executor of your choice). Is your question about the purpose of this function or the technical aspect of it?

Comment: @Vincent thanks for your comment, I would like to know the purpose of the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know the purpose of the function

The [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) awaitable has two main use cases:

1. Perform an I/O operation that cannot be managed through the file descriptor interface of the selector loop (i.e using the [loop.add/remove_reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_reader) methods). This happens occasionally, see how the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c5cb077ab3c88394b7ac8ed4e746bd31b53e39f1/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L849-L857) for [loop.getaddrinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.getaddrinfo) uses `loop.run_in_executor` under the hood for instance.
2. Perform a heavy CPU operation that would block the event loop context switching mechanism for too long. There are plenty of legitimate use cases for that, imagine running some data processing task in the context of an asyncio application for instance.